Running FastAPI and Kibana on AWS ECS
I am trying to run a FastAPI service that consumes a request and generates a response and additionally I am also running the EKS stack on this same docker container for logging. However when I try to run this on ECS and deploy the solution.
I am successfully able to call the API endpoints however I am getting an error "refused to connect" when I try to connect to the endpoint that runs Kibana (Port 5601). I am doing the correct port mapping on the task definition while creating the task on AWS.
I checked my security groups and see that they should allow everything however I still am not able to access the kibana service running on the ECS.
Any tips or suggestions?
My github with the project (on the branch logging-setup)
https://github.com/shivanshvermaa/mlops-deployment
This is the task definition I have
{
"family": "mlops-deployment-task",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "mlops-deployment-container",
        "image": "shivanshvermaa0/ml-ops-prodoction:latest",
        "cpu": 0,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "name": "mlops-deployment-container-80-tcp",
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            },
            {
                "name": "mlops-deployment-container-5601-tcp",
                "containerPort": 5601,
                "hostPort": 5601,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            },
            {
                "name": "mlops-deployment-container-9200-tcp",
                "containerPort": 9200,
                "hostPort": 9200,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "AWS_S3_OBJECT_NAME",
                "value": "<SECRET>"
            },
            {
                "name": "AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME",
                "value": "<SECRET>"
            },
            {
                "name": "AWS_SECRET_KEY",
                "value": "<SECRET>"
            },
            {
                "name": "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                "value": "<SECRET>"
            }
        ],
        "environmentFiles": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "volumesFrom": [],
        "ulimits": [],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "/ecs/mlops-deployment-task",
                "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
            },
            "secretOptions": []
        },
        "systemControls": []
    }
],
"executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<SECRET>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
],
"cpu": "1024",
"memory": "6144",
"ephemeralStorage": {
    "sizeInGiB": 21
},
"runtimePlatform": {
    "cpuArchitecture": "ARM64",
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
}

My network mapping for creating the service on the ECS cluster

The Security group configurations - I am allowing all traffic from my IP. I still am not able to access the 9200 and 5601 ports but I am able to make requests for the port 80.


I looked at the linked GitHub repo, but I just see some python code. I don't see any sort of CloudFormation or Terraform or other IaC code that would let us determine what is wrong with your infrastructure setup. The lack of details in your question make it impossible for anyone to determine what the issue may be.

I am not using terraform to create the services. Should I put the ECS Cluster's Json so that I can give a better picture? I am new to ECS!

You should put ALL the relevant info in your question.

Added all the relevant information. Let me know if anything is missing!

Is this behind a load balancer? Or are you hitting the tasks directly by their IP address?
